# Sonarqube exited with exit value [es]: 143

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarcube cor coded analysis and when I run the sonar.sh file I get this error "Process exited with exit value [es]: 143"

This is my configuration of sonar.properties

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://13.235.126.175:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.jdbc.username=s2ic
sonar.jdbc.password=S2ic@2019
sonar.web.port=9000
```

I am running sonarqube on ec2 instance and my db is hosted on another instance.

I tried searching for the error in the logs but couldn't find anything.What am I doing wrong? 
Any help would be appreciated

This is my web.log

```
2019.09.30 10:16:39 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[_client_][transport_worker][T#4]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.4/sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.4/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
 java.base@11.0.4/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)
 java.base@11.0.4/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:136)
 app//io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
 app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:765)
 app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:413)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019.09.30 10:16:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2019.09.30 10:16:39 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
```

This is my sonar.log

```
2019.09.30 10:16:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp
2019.09.30 10:16:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.09.30 10:16:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1/elasticsearch]: /newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.09.30 10:16:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.09.30 10:16:22 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.09.30 10:16:22 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.09.30 10:16:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2019.09.30 10:16:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*:/newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /newvolume/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp/sq-process12093467757608272782properties
2019.09.30 10:16:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
2019.09.30 10:16:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.09.30 10:16:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2019.09.30 10:16:40 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant logs, they might be helpful.

Comment: I have added them.

Comment: Did you start SonarQube as Root? That is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

you can see the details in `../sonarqube-8.4.1.35646/logs`, it show `Process[web] is stopped` first, you can see the `web.log`. There may be a problem with the database configuration.